# Closing workbook destroys variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I defined a class called "cSettings".  Then I created a cSettings object called "info".  The info object has a method to read data from a user selected workbook, then store them in its member variables.  The member variables are object type.  More specifically, "nested Dictionary" type.

What I've observed was - before closing the workbook, all data in the info object was good.  After closing the workbook, I'm "object required" message when accessing one of the member variables.  So it seems like closing the workbook has somehow destroy part of the data.  But how?  Here's my code:

```
' Class module cSettings

Option Explicit
Public obj1 As Object
Public obj2 As Object

' ----------

Public Sub ReadFrom(wb As Workbook)
    Set obj1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set obj2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set obj1 = Get1(wb, "sheet1")
    Set obj2 = Get2(wb, "sheet2")
End Sub

Private Function Get1(wb As Workbook, sh As String) As Dictionary
    Dim a_obj as object
    Set a_obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Read from workbook

    ' Add data to outer dictionary, creating inner dictionary
    a_obj.add "key1", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Add data to inner dictionary
    a_obj("key1").add "key11", "Value11"

    Set Get1 = a_obj
End Function

Private Function Get2(wb As Workbook, sh As String) As Dictionary
    Dim a_obj as object
    Set a_obj = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Read from workbook

    ' Add data to outer dictionary, creating inner dictionary
    a_obj.add "key2", CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' Add data to inner dictionary
    a_obj("key2").add "key21", "Value21"

    Set Get2 = a_obj
End Function
```

Here's the main program:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim info As New cSettings

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile, False, True)

    info.ReadFrom wb

    Debug.Print info.Items("key1")("key11").count '<-- OK
    Debug.Print info.Items("key2")("key21").count '<-- OK

    wb.Close

    Debug.Print info.Items("key1")("key11").count '<-- OK
    Debug.Print info.Items("key2")("key21").count '<-- Error "Object Required"
End Sub
```

Note: The above is not the original code because the original code is two long to paste.  But I was trying to understand why closing a workbook will have impact on a variable.  Would it be possible that the variable somehow is a 'pointer' to the workbook?  Thus when the workbook was closed, the actual data in the variable was also gone?  Thank you!

Comment: Try declaring `info` as a `Global` variable outside the subroutine.

Comment: @dwirony, thank you for your help.  May I know why info needs to be declared as Global?  why part of the data in "info" was gone but not all of them?  I'll try your suggestion and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: @Helloguys once you get to End Sub, `info` is out of scope, as are `myFile` and `wb` declaring them at module level means that they are still available to other subs/functions etc

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I only use `info` in the `main()` sub, why I want to declare it as global?  Also, some member variables in the `info` was OK, but some other member variable in `info` was corrupted/gone.  I don't understand what's the difference.

Comment: Just tried declaring the `info` as global.  Same error.

Comment: I don't think the code you posted accurately represents the problem you're having with your original code --- see the answer I posted, where I get the same output before and after closing the workbook.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as posted did not compile. With some modifications to get it to run, I'm unable to reproduce the errors:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim myFile As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim info As New cSettings

    myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile, False, True)

    info.ReadFrom wb

    Debug.Print info.obj1("key1")("key11") '<-- OK
    Debug.Print info.obj2("key2")("key21") '<-- OK

    wb.Close

    Debug.Print info.obj1("key1")("key11") '<-- OK
    Debug.Print info.obj2("key2")("key21") '<-- OK
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What did you modify?

Comment: `info.Items` would not compile so I changed that to `info.obj1` and `info.obj2`. `.count` would not compile so I printed the dictionary value instead.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out.

In my code I use `dictionary.Add` method to add a cell's content.  The original code was like `myDic.Add "key", ws.cells(r,c)`, where `ws` was referring to a worksheet of an opened workbook.  As a newbie, I thought it would take the value of the cell and simply add a `key, value` pair to the dictionary.

What it **actually** did was to add a pointer to that cell.  When the workbook is closed, of course that cell won't exist anymore.  Thus the content of the dictionary was corrupted.  I changed the code as below and it's working as expected:

```
val = ws.cells(r,c)
myDic.Add "key", val
```

Newbie question:  how do I tell VB use the value instead of reference?  Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you were doing `myDic.Add "key", ws.cells(r,c)`.  Use `myDic.Add "key", ws.cells(r,c).Value` instead

Comment: @Chris, thank you!  As a newbie, I kept forgetting the difference between cells(r,c) and cells(r,c).value as they usually returns the "same" result.  :)